# How do I find the number of floors in a building using power efficiency?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> An electrical motor of $80\%$ of power efficiency requires $6\,kW$ to
>   propel a centrifuge pump of $73.5\%$ of efficiency, which the latter
>   use it to raise the water from the basement to a water tank situated
>   in the rooftop of the building at a rate of $0.54 \frac{m^3}{min}$.
>   Find the number of floors that the building has if each of them has
>   $2.5\,m$ of height. You may use $g=9.8\,\frac{m}{s^2}$.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&14\,floors\\
2.&16\,floors\\
3.&12\,floors\\
4.&10\,floors\\
5.&18\,floors\\
\end{array}$

I'm still stuck on this problem as I don't know how should I use the information of the efficiency. The only thing which comes to my mind is this formula:

$\eta=\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}$

I'm assuming that "out" is the power which is produced by the process and "in" the power put in the process. But I'm confused on where should I put the percentages given and what should I do with the speed in cubic meters per minute. Can somebody help me?. Supposedly the answer is the second option. But I don't know how to get there.